# Sonarqube 6.7 Analyses suspended

Tags: .net

I have installed Sonarqube 6.7 and "Analyses suspended. Please set a valid license for the commercial features you installed.Go to License page." error appeared to me. I checked and I do not have any plugins that are commercial. Could I ask you to direct what the problem may be

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issues and could attribute it to the presence of the sonar-license and sonar-plsql plugins. It appears that the plsql plugin used to have a different license and SonarQube didn't handle this case gracefully during the upgrade to 6.7 (which saw the move to a different license model/implementation).

Double-check the "Marketplace" tab in the settings and see if there are any plugins marked as "Installed" with a checkmark next to them and no way of uninstalling them from the Web UI - if your problem is anything like ours, these are the likely culprits.

Comment: I remove all plugins, do restart sonarqube and install again from GUI, then everything started to work

Comment: did you remove  $SONARQUBEHOME/extensions/your-plugin? Same issue here